# Unable to create and install pgAgent service

Tags: postgresql, jobs, pgadmin, scheduled-tasks, troubleshooting

I'm trying to install pgAgent on my device. During the installation using the stackbuilder, the last step requires me to add the operating system username and password as below:
[image: last prompt window]

However, after entering the password of my postgres superuser account, i'm shown the below dialog box:

[image: dialog box]

Every resource available online mentions that the username and password should be the superuser's. I've tried using the Windows account details as well as creating a new user within postgres and using its details. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm using PostgreQL v13, and pgAgent v4.2.1